# WebView not correctly shown

Tags: android, webview

I created a app with Navigation Drawer. If I switch to a tab, in this case a `WebView`, the`WebView` is not correctly shown.
[Picture (area is marked)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMgsJ.png)

> Fragment:

```
public class StudentPlanFragment extends Fragment {

private WebView mWebView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_student_plan, null);
    mWebView = (WebView) rootView .findViewById(R.id.webViewStudentPlan);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://example.com");
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


    return rootView ;
}
}
```

> My XML-File:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="de.nichuhn.hlg.StudentPlanFragment"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:id="@+id/constraintLayout">


<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webViewStudentPlan"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: check my solution @N.Preusche

Answer (score 0):

First why do you use RelativeLayout ? If you just have the webView use this :

```
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/webViewStudentPlan"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />
```

The problem is with the bar on the top or the bottom ?

Comment: Did you try to replace your layout ? If yes please add your layout of the navigation drawer

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,

```
 mWebView = (WebView) rootView .findViewById(R.id.webViewStudentPlan);
 mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 mWebView.loadUrl("http://example.com");
```

that is, `loadUrl`is at last.

also check the internet permission in your `manifest.xml` like,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```